# Correct version of class which follows all SOLID Priciples

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I want to make a class which applies `Activation Function` to a value. The class is as follows

```
public class ActivationFunction {

    public static double function(double value, Functions functions) {
        if(functions.equals(Functions.SIGMOID)) {
            return sigmoid(value);
        }
        return 0f;
    }
    public static double derivativeOfFunction(double value, Functions functions) {
        if(functions.equals(Functions.SIGMOID))
            return sigmoidDerivative(value);

        return 0f;
    }

    private static double sigmoid(double value) {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(0 - value));
    }
    private static double sigmoidDerivative(double value) {
        return ( Math.exp(0 - value) / ( (1 + Math.exp(0 - value)) * (1 + Math.exp(0 - value)) ) );
    }

}
```

Where `Functions` is the `enum` in which different functions are defined. There is only `sigmoid` function now, but more will be added.

**QUESTION**

I thing it's violating the `Open-Closed Principle`, one of the 5 `SOLID` Principles of OOP (may be it's violating more). So, what is the correct way to write this class to accommodate addition of more functions in future?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't apply any SOLID principles here. It's not even an object. It has no state. It's just a collection of static methods. This is procedural, not OOP. A giveaway should be the class is called "...Function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the implementation of the common interface in the enum itself.

Something like this:

```
public enum Functions {
  SIGMOID {
    public double function(double value) { return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(0 - value)); }
    public double derivative(double value) { return ...; }
  },
  OTHER_FUNCTIONS { ... }

  public abstract double function(double value);
  public abstract double derivative(double value);
}
```

Your `ActivationFunction` then becomes very simple to write - it's probably not even useful any more.

Comment: I think this would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving your `enum` values behavior like this?

```
enum MyFunctions {
    FUNC_1 {
        @Override double compute(double value) {
            return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(0 - value));
        }
    },

    FUNC_2 {
        @Override double compute(double value) {
            return ( Math.exp(0 - value) / ( (1 + Math.exp(0 - value)) * (1 + Math.exp(0 - value)) ) );
        }
    };

    abstract double compute(double value);
}
```

Whenever you need more functions, define another enum value, like `FUNC_3`. If you need more than the one method `compute` add another method `compute2`.

All the names I selected are silly but I hope you get the point. Or did I missed the target of your question completely?

Comment: I can't think of a single reason you would ever want to use this "design pattern"

Comment: @Michael: and why not? Any reasonable explanation?

Comment: 1) `compute` is a meaningless name (and needs to be so to be generic enough to apply to both) 2) these enums are stateless, thus not object-oriented 3) it's basically a functor and we have lambdas for that now

Comment: How does my answer differ from the answer given by @assylias? Do you disagree with his answer as well? A stateful `enum` sounds strange to me.

Comment: It doesn't particularly. His is equally bad (in my opinion). I disagree. A *mutable* enum would be strange but an enum representing some constant state sounds fine.

Comment: Hence if I would have suggested not to override the method `compute` but instead provided a `Function<Double, Double>` to the constructor and store it in a field and than in `compute` delegate the call to that function by calling `field.apply()`, that would have pleased you more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143198/discussion-between-michael-and-harmlezz).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
public interface Function {
    double doIt(double value);
}

public class Sigmoid implements Function {
    @Override
    public double doIt(double value) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ActivationFunction {
    public static double callFunction(Function function,double value){
        return function.doIt(value);
    }
}
```

You should create a new class for new functions and implement Function interface. `callFunction` argument type `Function` , so you will not need to change it when you add a new function and it is correct for `Open-Closed Principle`.

Comment: This is better than the other answers but you have effectively redefined [`DoubleUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html)

Comment: I didn't know that Interface. So, is the correct answer _'use DoubleUnaryOperator'_ ?

Comment: In my opinion, yes maybe. Feel free to do some reading about it and edit your answer!